# c# winform update mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I have a code here that count the printed pages monthly:

```
public  void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult asyn)
    {
        try
        {

            CSocketPacket theSockId = (CSocketPacket)asyn.AsyncState ;//creating object of the class

            //end receive of data
            int iReceive  = 0 ;
            iReceive = theSockId.thisSocket.EndReceive (asyn);
            char[] chars = new char[iReceive +  1];
            System.Text.Decoder d = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder(); //creating object for decoding
            int charLen = d.GetChars(theSockId.dataBuffer, 0, iReceive, chars, 0);
            System.String szData = new System.String(chars);
            string test = count_page.Text + szData;
            string count_pages = Regex.Replace(test, "[^.0-9]", "");
            count_page.Text = count_pages;
            dbConnect.Update(count_pages); //problem lines
            //as data arrives the bytes are appended to the existing string printer throws data in an ASCII format 1 byte at a time

            WaitForData();
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException )
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0,"1","\nOnDataReceived: Socket has been closed\n");
        }
        catch(SocketException se)
        {
            MessageBox.Show (se.Message ); //gives an error message if any exception has occured
        }
    }
```

This code works fine if I dont put the line where I comment as problem line above :

```
dbConnect.Update(count_pages);
```

[image]

But I want it to be updated in the database, so I pass the value of counted pages to class dbConnect.Update. However, when I add this line. The value of count_pages seems did not display anymore in the text box, and it also did not pass the value to the dbConnect.Update class where the database cant update. Does anyone have any Idea why this haoppen?

Comment: Message box stops your method. You simply cant use it like that.

Comment: really?sorry I'm newbie. I actually just wanna test it because I wanna pass the value to the database class something like updateDB(count_pages). But seems that the value become empty. any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `Trace.WriteLine(count_pages);` instead of message box, because message box stops your method.

Dont forget to add `using System.Diagnostics;`

You can see result in `output` window, you can make it visible in `view` at visual studio top menu.

add:

About your new question, check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx2eya8(v=vs.110).aspx
and make something like that

```
private static void ReceiveCallback( IAsyncResult ar ) {
    try {
        // Retrieve the state object and the client socket 
        // from the asynchronous state object.
        StateObject state = (StateObject) ar.AsyncState;
        Socket client = state.workSocket;
        // Read data from the remote device.
        int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);
        if (bytesRead > 0) {
            // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer,0,bytesRead));
                //  Get the rest of the data.
            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer,0,StateObject.BufferSize,0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        } else {
            // All the data has arrived; put it in response.
            if (state.sb.Length > 1) {
                response = state.sb.ToString();
            }
            // Signal that all bytes have been received.
            receiveDone.Set();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited my question. Can you please take a look at my real problem and please give me advise on this?tq